# Nana or Nanna? (When Referring to Grandmother)

Tags: orthography

So, according to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nana) (English Dictionary), `Nana` is defined as one's grandmother, and `Nanna` redirects to `Nana`.

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/) (American Dictionary), `Nana` is one's grandmother, and `Nanna` is "The wife of Balder" (Scandinavian Mythology) or "The Sumerian god of the moon: the counterpart of the Akkadian god Sin".

A question was raised at this. I am Australian and have always spelt `Nana` as `Nana`. My brother, however, spells it as `Nanna`. The spell checker in Firefox is currently detecting `Nanna` to be correct to `Nana`.

My question is, in Australian/British English, how is `Nana` spelt? With one `n` or two?

Comment: Within the same family it's possible to use both spellings, either to refer to the same person (with different writers) or to differentiate between two grandmothers. (British experience). But as it's almost a nickname, spelling is more flexible than in normal writing

Comment: My kids called their mother's mother "mormor".

Comment: "Nanna" makes sense because it corresponds to "Nanny", but since when did English make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In British English, it would generally be spelt as 'Nana' without the double n. But as with the first comment, as a personal 'nickname' it could be spelled either way.

Comment: Please give supporting references. Unsupported answers tend to come across as (and have been known to be) mere opinion, perhaps error.

Answer (score -1):

In Stoke on Trent, England it his pronounced and spelt Nanar so it obviously changes with the local dialect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To show that yours is the right answer, consider adding explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Looking into this further, I found several pages on the internet ([example](https://www.justgiving.com/crowdfunding/Helpmygrandparents)) which could be used to support this answer.