# Does 'nana' mean just grandmother or grandmother from father's or mother's side?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

While I read [Nana or Nanna? (When Referring to Grandmother)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404497/nana-or-nanna-when-referring-to-grandmother) in wikitionary it also means one's grandmother https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nana, it doesn't tell whether it means grandmother from father's or mothers side or it doesn't matter ?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything at all to a lot of people.

Comment: It means whatever the child thinks it means.  If the child has two living grandmothers she likely will call one "Nana" and the other "Mormor", or some such.

Comment: In actual usage, it probably means whichever grandmother is Italian. But Italians only have one word for *grandmother* (*nonna*), so both grandmothers would  get called *Nana*.

Comment: It's used in the North of England and I know some Irish people who use it too. But you can't tell from the word alone  whether it's the paternal or maternal grandmother.

Comment: There are no rules or conventions. In most families it's down to the preferences of the individual grandmothers.

Comment: Still to be heard in the US as well. A coworker begged out early last week to go see her nana in hospital.

Answer (score 1):

Among Germanic languages, only the Scandinavian tongues make a distinction between maternal and paternal grandparents, conveniently doing so with compounds: *mormor*, lit. mothermother, is a maternal grandmother and *farmor*, lit. fathermother, a paternal one.

For *grandmother*, both German and English originally prefixed *mother* with *old(er)*: OE *ældmoder*, ME [*eldmoder*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/eldmother); Low German *[Eldermutter, Ellermutter](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gro%C3%9Feltern)*, but under the influence of French *grand mére*, became *grandmother* and *Großmutter*. In German, the French for *aunt* and *uncle* also [supplanted terms](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verwandtschaftsbeziehung#Onkel_und_Tante) that originally made a distinction between paternal and maternal.

Since English has never made a distinction between maternal and paternal grandparents, less formal terms such as *nan/nanna* will not do so either. *Gran*, for instance, was my paternal grandfather, but many people call their grandmothers that. To my cousins (father's brother's children) he was Papa, and their mother's mother was Nanna. How these names or nicknames are used varies from family to family with no general lexical agreement.